# Rremove two params from my url (random order)

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying the IIS Rewrite module and I've tried several options:

- One rule with two input conditions
- Two rules; one for &folderCTID and another one for &view

Here two sample urls:

```
http://acme.com/DEPT/PD/APU-32/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fDEPT%2fPD%2fAPU-32%2fShared%20Documents%2fPhase%203%20Test%20and%20Evaluation%2fDVT&**FolderCTID**=&**View**=%7b9D83DDF0-3265-4E21-99AB-F23D1957BC71%7d

http:/acme.com/DEPT/PD/ETS-364/PRODUCT/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fDEPT%2fPD%2fETS-364%2fPRODUCT%2fDV%2fCompatibility%20Testing%20for%20Diags%2fNR%2fASM4736%20SN1004%20with%20QHSU&View=%7b377CF0F6-F2FD-46B4-BEE4-CF7C225ECC0B%7d&FolderCTID=
```

- Params could be in any order and may have or not values.
- One param could be missing in the url or both

Expected URL:
http://acme.com/DEPT/PD/APU-32/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fDEPT%2fPD%2fAPU-32%2fShared%20Documents%2fPhase%203%20Test%20and%20Evaluation%2fDVT

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rule like this. It can work in my IIS.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bruce, its not working for this url https://acme.com/sites/ETS_PD_IRON-EAGLE/PROJECT/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/sites/ETS_PD_IRON-EAGLE/PROJECT/QA/SV&View={CF263F01-F61B-485E-A7CB-C176576FC11A}&FolderCTID=123